# Handle website scroll offset based on mobile screen size

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I need to make this div visible if can scroll to left ,

```
<div class="fade-left" [class.visible]="showFadeLeft()"></div>

 public showFadeLeft() {
    return this.boxToolbarElement.nativeElement.scrollWidth - 
           Math.abs(this.boxToolbarElement.nativeElement.scrollLeft) !== 
           this.boxToolbarElement.nativeElement.clientWidth;
   }
```

> this.boxToolbarElement is the container of overflowing content .

The problem is when I open site in mobile the "fade-left" div be always shown , because display size (screen zoom) make "showFadeLeft() method" return different values , how can I handle any screen size .

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE**: **you should never use a FUNCTION inside HTML**. It may cause some side effects and will decrease your application performance.

**Solution**

```
<div class="fade-left" [class.visible]="isVisible"></div>
```

**App.component.ts**

```
isVisible = false;                  // initial value can be false or tru; 

ngAfterViewInit(){                  // This life cycle hook will make sure that nativeElement is available for further operation.

   this.showFadeLeft();

}


private showFadeLeft() {           // Added private keyword

    this.isVisible = this.boxToolbarElement.nativeElement.scrollWidth - 
           Math.abs(this.boxToolbarElement.nativeElement.scrollLeft) !== 
           this.boxToolbarElement.nativeElement.clientWidth;
}
```